# What is the latex code of this E/Epsilon variation? (Detexify didn't work)

Tags: fonts

[image: Unknown E/Epsilon variation]

I've found it in the book "Introduction to Quantum Optics" written by Grynberg, et-al... and I'd like to use it in my discussion on this title.

I've already try on Detexify but failed.

Comment: Looks like \mathcal{E}.

Comment: Or maybe `\mathscr{E}`

Comment: It's probably just a glyph from some font; you can try using the same font, or just draw your own.

Comment: You can load `\usepackage{mathrsfs,rsfso}` and then try`$\mathcal{E}$ $\mathscr{E}$` in the document. None of them is a 100% match.

Comment: Alternative duplicate [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is [Linoscript](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/linoscript/linoscript) (commercial)

[image]